# SharePoint 2010: Add GroupBy to existing list view using JSOM?

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, view, jsom

Is it possible to modify an existing view, more specific adding GroupBy, using JavaScript / JSOM? I am creating the library using JavaScript and I'd like to add a GroupBy in the "all items" default view.

```
var myView = this.list.get_views().getByTitle("All items");
myView.add(...?)
```

Comment: Please look into it if it helps you...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Answer (score 0):

You would use CAML inside your JavaScript, here's how to use it:

http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2014/10/adding-an-xsltlistviewwebpart-with-a-custom-view-using-javascript/